# Create a session when i select any option in select box using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a session when I select an option in a select box. But it's not working, I am not even getting the value from the select box. I am using `isset($_POST['SelectBoxName'])`, is there any alternative?

I am trying the below code, but it's not working.

I already have another session in the same program, will it be a problem ? It is used for some other process, and I want to create another session for some other process, but both should be in the same program. The another session is working perfectly, but this is not.

```
<?php
echo "<td><select name='cartQuantity' style='width:50px;' onchange='ajaxQuantityChange()'";             
    for($q=1;$q<=30;$q++)
    {
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
        {
    ?>                      
    <option value="<?php echo $q; ?>" <?php if($q==$key2){ ?>selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo $q; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    }
echo "</select></td>";                  

//CREATE A SESSION
if(isset($_POST['cartQuantity']))
{
    $_SESSION['cartQuantity']=$_POST['cartQuantity'];
}
?>
```

This is "ajaxquantitychange" function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxQuantityChange()
{
    var quantity;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        quantity=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        quantity=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    quantity.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(quantity.readyState==4 && quantity.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("finalPrice").innerHTML=quantity.responseText;
        }
    }
    quantity.open("GET","finalPrice.php",true);
    quantity.send();
} </script>
```

My whole code is in this link. Please check it and can someone give me the solution for my question? https://www.mediafire.com/?8iv6gcaox2crogh

Comment: You do submit that form, right ?

Comment: Post code of `ajaxQuantityChange`

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your line,

```
echo "<td><select name='cartQuantity' style='width:50px;' onchange='ajaxQuantityChange()'";
```

You didn't closed `select` tag. It should be

```
echo "<td><select name='cartQuantity' style='width:50px;' onchange='ajaxQuantityChange()'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is rather untidy. You could write it like:

```
<?php
    echo "<td><select name='cartQuantity' style='width:50px;' onchange='ajaxQuantityChange()'>"; 
    for ($q = 1; $q < 30; $q++)
        echo "<option value='$q'" . ($q == $key2 ? " SELECTED" : "") . ">$q</option>";
    echo "</select></td>"
?>
```

To use sessions, you must first use `session_start();`

You can end a session with `session_destroy();`